# Arrastar item do list para o lado

Tags: android, listview

Estava mexendo no meu celular e vi uma funcionalidade que eu gostaria de utilizar nos meus aplicativos , quando entro em contatos ai pego um contato e arrasto ele para a esquerda pega um evento de enviar sms e quando arrasto para a direito pega um evento de ligação , alguem sabe como fazer isto?

Comment: 1 - Comece estudando o manual: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html 2 - Depois veja este exemplo: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html 3 - Estude mais e faça mais códigos. Quando houver um problema, venha aqui e insira seu código e diga como podemos ajudar.

Comment: Este exemplo não funciona